# 'While' based menu doesn't work

Tags: python, menu, while-loop

This menu isn't working and I can't find the reason because I don't get any errors, but it's  still not the desired return value.

I think the problem is somewhere in the while loop:

```
def mainMenu():
    """ Main menu for the aplication"""
    mainMenuPrint()

    def m():
        inp=''
        while inp!='q':
            inp = str(input('enter option: '))      
            print'aaa'     #test 
            if inp == '1' or 'game': gameMenu()
            elif inp == 'admin' or 'administration' or '2': adminMenu()
            elif inp == 'quit' or '0': inp ='q' 
            else:
                print 'wrong input!'
            print 'bbb' #test
    m()
```

### `mainMenuPrint()`  is just a  string print

PYTHON 2.7

As i said i get no error, but   none of the input works, it keeps poping 'enter option'

Comment: With which input does it not work properly?

Comment: @kindall: If he "doesn't get any errors" as he's saying, it should be Python 2.

Comment: Then I'd expect an error when he types `q`, because he's using `input()` rather than `raw_input()`... I guess it doesn't matter which he's using since it won't run with either, but it would be nice to know what needed to be fixed.

Comment: Are you calling `mainMenu()` at some point in your code? What's the "not desired output" that you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

For a starter, you may want to substitute your `if inp == 'something' or 'someotherthing' or 'athridthing'` idioms with `if inp in ('something', 'someotherthing', 'athirdthing')` because `or` just tests the truth value of e.g. `'someotherthing'` instead of hooking on the equality test, thus evaluating any of your tests to `True`.

Example:

```
>>> a = '2'
>>> if a == '1' or '2': print 'hey'
... 
hey
>>> a = 'c'
>>> if a == '1' or '2': print 'hey'
... 
hey
```

As you see, even if `a` is assigned different string than the ones tested in the `if` condition written as you write yours, the condition is evaluated to `True`.

On the contrary:

```
>>> a = '2'
>>> if a in ('1', '2'): print 'hey'
... 
hey
>>> a = 'c'
>>> if a in ('1', '2'): print 'hey'
... 
>>>
```

Hope this starts to help.

Comment: +1. The key thing to note is that `if a == '1' or '2'` is not the same as `if a == '1' or a == '2'`.

Comment: @Giulio  thanks man for taking you time  you made it really clear
chepner  thank you, that was the problem....

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a = 3) or (1 != 0):
```

has the same meaning of

```
if (a = 3) or (1):
```

that as the same meaning of

```
    if (a = 3) or 1:
```

that than is always true 
You should write

```
if inp == '1' or inp == 'game': gameMenu()
```

to get your menu works.